# I have nodejs but not able to upgrade it by homebrew, what should I do?

Tags: node.js

I am on Mac `11.6 (20G165)`.

I have node.js v10 installed and want to upgrade to v12.

However, when I type `brew upgrade node`, I got this:

```
$brew upgrade node
Error: node not installed
```

I think it's because I didn't install node via `homebrew` before. But it's been such a long time and I couldn't remember what exact source/channel did I choose to install node long ago.

So what I can do to fix all this?

Comment: Have you tried using NVM?

Comment: No. Should I directly install nvm even if node is already installed?

Comment: Does `brew upgrade nodejs` work?

Comment: NVM is for managing multiple Node versions

Comment: @NerdOfLinux got `nodejs not installed`.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ thanks, I know that. I don't need multiple node versions and I'm wondering how to upgrade my current node without messing up anything. I just installed nvm. So what should I do with nvm to upgrade the current version to latest?

Comment: Hi, would you give me feedback about my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you have NVM installed you can run:

```
nvm install 12.14.1
```

then set the default Node with:

```
nvm alias default v12.14.1
```

Validate:

```
node -v
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the problem is with the installed version. you are not installed `nodejs` with `homebrew` previously.

So, if you want to install it with `brew` and use its benefits (like upgrading) try to uninstall the currently installed version with the instruction in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x).

Then, install the latest version via `brew` command:

```
brew install node
```

More on [brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/node) documentation.